# Will we be able to access life events on a timeline?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

Is Facebook planning to add functionality to allow developers to access the new "life events" posted on a user's timeline?
How about those posted on a friend's timeline?

Thanks!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

Comment: Thanks for this.  I reviewed that document and couldn't find any information relating to whether Facebook will publish API access to "life events".  Do you have any data in this area?  I appreciate it.

Comment: Given that that is their current roadmap, if it's not on there ... it's not planned. Or if it is, no one outside of their internal development groups knows about it (which means no one here on StackOverflow knows anything about it).

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/121450681328551/

Answer (score 4):

Life events are not currently readable via the API for a user or their friends.

Keep an eye on the updates at http://developers.facebook.com/blog which is where we'll announce this functionality if and when its it built.

if you're building an app which wants to publish life events, the best current suggestion is to model them as custom actions and custom objects on the open graph and build timeline aggregations which show these objects off to at their best.

Comment: Could you show me an example Graph API query that returns life event data (with the access_key and any incriminating personal data blanked out, of course)?

Answer (score 0):

The bug reported on facebook about this issue was closed on 3rd October 2013. So, I don't think anybody at Facebook is working on making this feature available via API.

Read: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/121450681328551/