# Fetch the facebook events using FB Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will we be able to access life events on a timeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642638/will-we-be-able-to-access-life-events-on-a-timeline)

I want to fetch an event using facebook api like wedding anniversary etc using facebook graph API. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to Facebook Graph API.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/